# SQL Server trigger with insert, update, delete

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Previously, I have created 3 triggers individually for insert, update, and delete actions.

The triggers are supposed to modify a value in another table when one of these happen.

When I try to create one combined trigger for all 3 actions (insert, update, and delete), I get many errors when trying to execute it. I've tried both case statements and if statements, but cannot tell what is going wrong.

```
CREATE TRIGGER multipurposeCourseEnrollment
    ON courseEnrollment AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE AS
        BEGIN 
            IF EXISTS(SELECT courseID FROM DELETED) AND EXISTS(SELECT courseID FROM INSERTED)
                THEN
                    DECLARE @oldCourseID INT
                    DECLARE @newCourseID INT
                    SELECT @oldCourseID = (SELECT courseID FROM DELETED)
                    SELECT @newCourseID = (SELECT courseID FROM INSERTED)
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE courses SET courseOpenSeats = (courseOpenSeats +1)
                            WHERE courseID = @oldCourseID
                        UPDATE courses SET courseOpenSeats = (courseOpenSeats -1)
                            WHERE courseID = @newCourseID AND courseOpenSeats>0
                    END
            ELSE
            IF EXISTS(SELECT courseID FROM DELETED)
                THEN
                    DECLARE @courseIDDel INT
                    SELECT @courseIDDel = (SELECT courseID FROM DELETED)
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE courses SET courseOpenSeats = (courseOpenSeats +1)
                            WHERE courseID = @courseIDDel
                    END
            ELSE
            IF EXISTS(SELECT courseID FROM UPDATED)
                THEN
                    DECLARE @courseID INT
                    SELECT @courseID = (SELECT courseID FROM UPDATED)
                    BEGIN


        UPDATE courses SET courseOpenSeats = (courseOpenSeats - 1)
                        WHERE courseID = @courseID AND courseOpenSeats>0
                END
        ELSE
        END)
    END;
```

One problem may be how I declared the `@variables`. Not sure if this is correct.

The error I get is :

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.*

I also get this for `ELSE`

Comment: Quite honestly: I'd recommend to have **three separate** triggers - that's much easier to work with, you can disable the `INSERT` trigger if you need, and the amount of code in each trigger is just in a manageable range. This is just a **HUGE** monster - how are you going to maintain this over the next 2, 3, 5 years??

Comment: Oh this isn't for anything in particular. I am just learning databases and saw online this can be done, but in the other examples, I haven't seen anyone use a trigger with 3 conditions to update tables. In their examples, it is usually to create a log and that code seems to be more simple.

Comment: 'IF EXISTS(SELECT courseID FROM UPDATED)' <-- there is no UPDATE table to read from. If you work with SQL server you have to fetch from INSERTED or DELETED.

Comment: Two remarks: first, you can have many records affected - thereby better not to use variables, but only set operations. Second, don't worry about updates - update operations can be seen as subsequent delete and insert; you have to adjust your seats count just both for deletes and inserts. And - better let your seats count go below zero, otherwise your calculation will remain wrong after erroneus deletes.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your triggers are as :

1. There is no any updated table , updated case you have already check using first condition.
   i.e case of (deleted and inserted).
2. Second one is that after 
   `IF EXISTS(---condition---)` you **have to use** `BEGIN` and `END` not `THEN` and `END`.
   That is also a syntax error you may have also faced many times in that query.

Hope this helped you.